# Character count and then Trim

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function

I know how to count number of characters in Excel using

```
=LEN(A1)
```

My question is if the character length count is greater then 3000 it should trim all the data that is above 3000, is it possible in Excel?

Comment: **Side note:** if you're in VBA you can dimension a String variable like this `Dim s as String * 3000` and then when you say `s = Range("A1")` it will pick up only first `3000` characters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`LEFT()`](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/left.php) function to achieve that. As pnuts kindly points out in the comments, we actually don't have to check with `LEN()` first if the cell's length is bigger than 3000 characters, we can use the `LEFT()` function immediately:

```
=LEFT(A1, 3000)
```

where `A1` is the cell you need to shorten if it is too long.